# map } but not after y

Tags: key-bindings

I have remapped <kbd>}</kbd> as follows `noremap } }jz.` so that as I go down paragraphs the cursor stays in the middle of the screen and to the first line of the next paragraph (usually).

That works fine. But I also use <kbd>}</kbd> after <kbd>y</kbd> to yank say the next 3 paragraphs to paste elsewhere. For example <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>.  In this usage, I want Vim to ignore my mapping. (The rationale is that after a <kbd>y</kbd> there is no movement, so my modification to the movement should also be ignored after a <kbd>y</kbd>.)

Is there a way to map a movement key, but have a mapping be ignored after <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, and perhaps even after number prefixes such as <kbd>2</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nnoremap` instead of `noremap`. Mode after pressing <kbd>y</kbd> is `Operator-pending` and that could be addressed by `onoremap`. You can read more about modes in `:h map-modes`.